# Estimate how many user that can handle in every instance of signalr app

Tags: c#, performance, signalr

I want to know are there any tools that can run a SignalR app on my PC and estimate how many users that app can handle.

Are there any tools? Any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crank was developed by the SignalR team for exactly this purpose. [Here is an article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=914) that explains how to use Crank to perform load testing on a SignalR app.

It's a pretty complex topic- so I would advise reading the whole article.

Comment: Toms bang on here. Use Crank. Don't try and  and do this yourself. Generating thousands of clients is a complex and non-trivial problem. We successfully managed to generate 20K concurrent connections but we needed a few machines and relied heavily on crank... we mnodified the source to work against persistent connections....